# recover SQL table from a database after dropping and creating

Tags: sql

I was working in a different database and just noticed a table that has the same name in a of another in a different database has been dropped and created again like the one in my current database. Is there a way to recover the old one or the rows? Please it's very important.

Comment: Kindly ask the DBA to restore a back-iuo,

Comment: I meant _back-up_...

Comment: Which DB are you using?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score -1):

Managed to get the deleted data from a different server. Problem solved. This was in SSMS, there was a server with the same database and i just copied the values

Comment: How? And which database?

Comment: SSMS with a backup server which i didn't know existed